# Website layout issue

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a website completed but I am having an issue. I have a sidebar with links to other pages on the left side of the screen in green. the rest of the content is to right of the sidebar in yellow. The problem I'm having is that the site looks fine on my screen but, of I view the site in a larger or small resolution the text and other content is shifted into the green of the sidebar. I have the width of the body set to 100%. I am unsure what the problem is. 
CSS:

```
body
{
    background-image:url(Images/testbackground.jpg);
    width:100%


}

#Links
{
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 200px;



}



#ContentLayout
{
    clear: right;
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
    font-size:18px;
}



#wrapper
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:100%;

}
```

HTML:

```
<body>

<!--[if lte IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="OldHome.css" />
<![endif]-->

<div id="wrapper">

<img src="Images/logo.jpg" name="Logo" id="Logo"  />


<div id="Links">
  <a href="index.html"><img src="Images/HomeLogo.jpg" alt="home" border="0px" /></a>
  <br />
  <a href="Programs.html"><img src="Images/ProgramsLogo.jpg" alt="programs" border="0px" /></a>
  <br />
  <a href ="Services.html"><img src="Images/ServicesLogo.jpg" alt="services" border="0px" /></a>
  <br />
  <a href ="Contact.html"><img src="Images/ContactLogo.jpg" alt="contact" border="0px" /></a>
  <br />
  <a href ="OtherLinks.html"><img src="Images/OtherLinksLogo.jpg" alt="links" border="0px" /></a>
  <br />
  <a href ="FAQ.html"><img src="Images/FAQLogo.jpg" alt="faq" border="0px" /></a>
  <br />
  <a href="Feedback.html"><img src="Images/FeedBackLogo.JPG" alt="feedback" border="0px" /></a>
  <br />
  <a href="Photos.html"><img src="Images/PhotosLogo.JPG" alt="photos" border="0px" /></a>
</div>

<div id="header"> 
    <h1><center>

  <u>Home</u>

  <p><img src="Images/OutsideBld2.jpg" width="600" height="500" /></p>
    </center></h1>
</div>
    <div id="ContentLayout">
      <h3 style="padding-left:30px"><center>Mission Statement</center></h3>
<p id="MissionStatement">The Employment Preparation Centre offers employment assistance programs and services to clients at no charge. These are available on a one-on-one basis or in group settings.

Programs and services at The Employment Preparation Centre are based on a belief that a person’s employability is enhanced through &nbsp;self-assessment, knowledge of the current labour market, and development of a return-to-work action plan.</p>
<p id="MissionStatement">
Programs and services at The Employment Preparation Centre are funded through the Department of Advanced Education and Skills under several key divisions.
</p>
<br />
<br />

<p>Trouble finding us?</p>
<!-- Google map START -->
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=10+Main+Street,+Corner+Brook&amp;aq=&amp;sll=39.017445,-98.196116&amp;sspn=35.694805,86.044922&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=10+Main+St,+Corner+Brook,+Division+No.+5,+Newfoundland+and+Labrador+A2H+1C6,+Canada&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=48.951917,-57.947721&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br /><small><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=10+Main+Street,+Corner+Brook&amp;aq=&amp;sll=39.017445,-98.196116&amp;sspn=35.694805,86.044922&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=10+Main+St,+Corner+Brook,+Division+No.+5,+Newfoundland+and+Labrador+A2H+1C6,+Canada&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;ll=48.951917,-57.947721" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">View Larger Map</a></small>
<!-- Google map END -->
<p>This page has <span><?=$hits;?></span> hits</p>
<address>

&copy; 2012
</address>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var $buoop = {}
      $buoop.ol = window.onload;
      window.onload=function(){
        if ($buoop.ol) $buoop.ol();
        var e = document.createElement("script");
    e.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        e.setAttribute("src", "http://browser-update.org/update.js");
        document.body.appendChild(e);
      }
    </script>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe you can JSFiddle it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the position on you areas and text is set to absolute?

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is your width. #Links is always 10% of the screen and the content area is always 80% of the screen. so if you make the viewport smaller there is always the 10% and the 80% allocation. The font stays the same so it tries to fit the text in the 10% and the 80% areas.

Maybe you should give the try it with absolute width and [mediaqueries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)

Here is a fiddle, its still crappy css but it works (added a fix links width)
http://jsfiddle.net/dennym/AGt9L/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if you have all column widths in percentage the site may look crappy in some resolutions (viewport widths).
I suggest that you make the menubar a fixed size (e.g. 200px) and give the content div `width: auto` (i.e. no width). Both div's should be left floated. Make the wrapper also fixed size.
In this way, the two containers are beside eachother. The menu column has fixed width and the content column has the width that adds up to the parent width, which is the width of the wrapper.

I restructured your HTML code as well.

Here is a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mikey/Wmms3/) (images not working and CSS still little crappy).

Answer (score 0):

I think that your order of markup could be to blame. If you shifted things around like [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SWaEX/), the layout is much more adaptable, without having to position:absolute;